# How can I use the Node.js 'async' module to do 'A' or 'B' and then always 'C' in one function?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to avoid some minor Node.js javascript callback hell of this flavor:

I must do either a long asynchronous process A or B and then always follow up with C. In psuedocode:

```
function example(flag, callback) {
    if (flag) {
        doLongProcessA(function(err, result) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            doLongProcessC(result, function(err, finalResult) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                return callback(null, finalResult);
            });
        });
    } else {
        doLongProcessB(function(err, result) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            doLongProcessC(result, function(err, finalResult) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                return callback(null, finalResult);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The two 'doLongProcessC' calls are not very DRY. I'd rather not split the function into two parts (one with A or B and one with C for them to call). It feels like the Node package 'async' can solve this problem, but I don't know how. Can anyone give an example solution? Thanks!

Comment: You could do something like `(flag ? doLongProcessA : doLongProcessB)(function ...)`

Comment: If you're using async, you'll have to split the function into separate parts, but it's not that painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, async is a good choice to avoid callback hell in your code.

async.waterfall allows every function in the "pipeline" to pass its results to the next function.

In your example, both A and B are passing their results to the next function C.

You can use async waterfall as follows:

```
function example(flag, next) {

    async.waterfall(
        [
            function(callback) {
                if (flag) {
                    doLongProcessA(callback);
                } else {
                    doLongProcessB(callback);
                }
            },
            // If you want to differentiate the behavior of C in terms of flag, 
            // uncomment the flag param below
            function(/*flag,*/ result, callback) { 
                doLongProcessC(/*flag,*/ result, callback);
            }
        ],
        // if any function in the pipeline throws an err, 
        // it will immediately call this final function and return 
        function(err, result) {
            if (err!= null) {
                // put error handlers here
                return next(err);
            }
            // return the result
            return next(null, result);
        }
    };  
}
```

and doLongProcessA and doLongProcessB should look like this:

```
doLongProcessAorB(callback) 
{
    if (err) return callback(err, null)
    // do something here to fetch the result
    callback(null, /*flag, */ result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer promises for this, if you can use them.

```
function example(flag, callback) {
  var longProcess = (flag) ? processa() : processb();
  longProcess
    .then(processc(callback))
    .fail(callback); // callback will be called with `err` argument
    // .done(doalways)) // if you need something like this
}

function processc(callback) {
  return function(results) {
    // do something with results
    callback(null, finalResults);
  }
}
```

**Update** More promise, less callback aggregator.

```
function processa() {
  // do long process then `resolve(results)` when done or `reject(err)` on error
}

function processb() {
  // do long process then `resolve(results)` when done or `reject(err)` on error
}

function example(flag) {
  var longProcess = flag ? processa() : processb();
  return longProcess
    .then(function(results) {
      // process results
      return finalResults;
    });
}

var ex = example(flag)
  .then(function(finalResults) {
    // do something with final results
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    // do something on fail
  });
```

Comment: Don't mix callbacks and promises, this kind of promise use is completely useless :|